# How to pass a list from spring controller to ajax in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

This is my Jquery! Here i am not getting success response, instead a error response is thrown when a list is returned from controller to below jquery. Please let me know where i am going wrong.

```
//ajax method to retrieve the data from controller where controller returns list
function doAjaxPost() {
  // get the form values
  var pid = $('#pid').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8085/HMS/iochart1.html",
    data: "pid=" + pid,

    success: function (response) {
      alert(response.list4);
      $.each(response, function (index, datec) {
        alert(datec.name); //to print name of employee
      });
    },
    // Even though controller returns the list,but i am not getting the above success response,instead below error method is executed. 
    error: function (e) {
      alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
  });
}
```

Below is the controller which returns the list.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/iochart1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Iochart> iochart1(@ModelAttribute("s") Iochart s) {
  System.out.println("Patient"+s.getPid());
  List<Iochart> list4 = dao.getPatientdet1(s.getPid());
  return list4;
}
```

getPatientdet1() which retrieves the data from database

```
public List<Iochart> getPatientdet1(String pid) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.out.println(pid);
  return template.query(
    "select pid,name,fileno,age,gender,date,wardno,doctord,doctsig,ratef,nursesig,time,type,amount,typecommence,amtgiv,urine,vomitus,remarks from iochart where pid='"+pid+"'",
    new RowMapper<Iochart>() {  
      public Iochart mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {   
        Iochart i = new Iochart();
        i.setPid(rs.getString(1));
        i.setName(rs.getString(2));
        i.setFileno(rs.getString(3));
        i.setAge(rs.getString(4));
        i.setGender(rs.getString(5));
        i.setAdmdate(rs.getString(6));
        i.setWardno(rs.getString(7));
        i.setDoctord(rs.getString(8));
        i.setDoctsig(rs.getString(9));
        i.setRatef(rs.getString(10));
        i.setNursesig(rs.getString(11));
        i.setTime(rs.getString(12));
        i.setOraltype(rs.getString(13));
        i.setOralamt(rs.getString(14));
        i.setOralcommence(rs.getString(15));
        i.setAmtgiv(rs.getString(16));
        i.setUrine(rs.getString(17));
        i.setVomitus(rs.getString(18));
        i.setRemarks(rs.getString(19));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        return i;
      }
        }
  );
}
```

Comment: The JavaScript code seems Ok. Does Java service returns Http response status "200 Ok"? It can be checked in web browser developer tools network tab (F12 hotkey). Also make sure there is no issues about Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) . The JavaScript page and Java service should belong to the same hostname and port.

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller method like so. Mind the `@RequestParam` that is used to get the pid

```
@RequestMapping(value="/iochart1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Iochart> iochart1(@RequestParam(name = "pid") String pid) {
    return dao.getPatientdet1(pid);
}
```

And your ajax url like so

```
function doAjaxPost() {
    // get the form values
    var pid = $('#pid').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8085/HMS/iochart1", //Don't postfix .hmtl
        data: "pid=" + pid,
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: did you try this sir?